# selecting current match from the cricket schedule using mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a cricket schedule and i need to select the matches of the current day just half an hour before the match starts and the selection should last until the 2 hours past the end of the match , this should be done in a single query i have used the following query but it is not working accurately...

```
SELECT * FROM `schedule` WHERE  
   date1  BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MInute) 
              AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 HOUR)
```

Comment: Is `date1` the start time? Then what is the end time?

Comment: Aside from other issues, un-indent your question and indent your SQL.

Comment: date1 is obviously the beginning of the match. Is there another date field, i.e., date2, to represent the end of the match ?

Comment: end time is 12 hours from start time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display all scheduled matches from half an hour before they start until 2 hours after they end, and all mathces have a duration of 12 hours, then you need to show all matches within a 14,5 hours interval, and not a 10,5 hours interval as your current code does:

```
SELECT * FROM `schedule` 
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN DATE_SUB(date1, INTERVAL 30 Minute) 
                AND DATE_ADD(date1, INTERVAL 14 HOUR)
```

Furthermore, you should compare the current time (`NOW()`) to the start time and end time of the game, not the other way round.